# How to make 'if button clicked, do this' in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore

I am new to Android Studio. I am working on a ArCore sample project.
I want to add a button, when clicked the plane finding mode will be vertical otherwise horizontal.
Before voting negative, I have gone through these posts:
[How can I write “if button clicked” in an If statement in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528545/how-can-i-write-if-button-clicked-in-an-if-statement-in-android-studio)

[Checking if a button has been clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661425/checking-if-a-button-has-been-clicked)

The following is the snippet of my code:

```
if(y > 0){
            Config config = new Config(session);
            
            
            //config.setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.VERTICAL); If button clicked, this
            config.setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.HORIZONTAL); //otherwise this
            session.configure(config);
            Globals.notRecording = true;


        }
```

Comment: if you are completely new to android, i don't think working on an AR project is going to be a good experience for you, why not start with actual basics ?

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // Perform action on click   

            }
          });
```

Just use this code in `OnClickListener`.
when you tap button call this

```
config.setPlaneFindingMode(Config.PlaneFindingMode.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: OP doesn't seem to know how to create an `onClickListener` so i don't think this answer is useful

Comment: @a_local_nobody is my answer correct now?

Comment: not really, the question doesn't have enough detail to provide a correct answer

Comment: so what do I do now? delete my answer or what?